# Admin page for every special page

Tags: views, nodes, users

I'm creating a web site in Drupal 7, there are home page, and three main taxonomy pages(they are primary links), the client is asking, to tell the truth they are insisting on me to make custom admin pages for every primary pages, sounds like primitive but they want to control every part of the main pages manually. How can I handle this task? I've already created these pages with views. Has anybody faced before with this type of issue?

Comment: What you've made is awesome. +1

Comment: Nikhil Mohan any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Depends on what you've done already?

Comment: i've only displaying these contents in by means of views on the main pages, they are sorted automatically, by fields, dates and comment numbers, main contents are showing up by date desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "custom admin pages", but to give complete control over the layout of the content you could use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and perhaps also [Panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer).  The Panels in-place editor is probably enough for the client's needs, but you might show them the backend editor instead because it looks (and is) far more powerful/complicated.  It may even have the benefit of scaring them away from having the control themselves and asking you to go back to your original plan.

EDIT:

Here's how I would go about this using Panels, Views, Rules, and Flag.  This may not be the most optimal way, but it uses well-supported modules.

1. Make a panel for the home page.
2. Make a flag for each section that needs to appear on the home page.
3. Make a view (content pane) for each section.  The view should display the most recent node tagged with the flag for that section.  Add each view to the appropriate place on the home page panel.
4. Add a rule that, when a node is flagged, uses the trim flag action to ensure that only one node is flagged with that flag at any given time.

If you do this, your content editors can simply flag the pages they want and they will be displayed in the appropriate sections automatically.  (I have used all these modules to do a similar thing in the past, though I have not built this exact workflow.)

Comment: i don't think that the Panels is not the clue key of the situation, Panels and Panelizer are mostly used in the backend of the site, right?

Comment: Yes, it is used on the backend, but it is used to provide content creators/site administrators with an easy-to-use way to modify the layout and content of the site.  Panels was developed for Sony Music to manage their large number of artists' pages.

Comment: but in my situation client is asking not to change the layout of the pages, but the layout remains as it is, but nodes inside of the panels will be changed manually

Comment: In that case, you could try a combination of Panels, Flag, Views, and Rules.  See my update above for details.

Comment: i'll try to handle it with the modules that you mentioned, but besides i think custom module needs to be created

Comment: Patrick maybe you have misundertood this issue, in some cases your way can be correct, but in this particular matter i'd rather not follow it